# Reset the column position of a CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I read a csv file into a dataframe

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\x01", header=None)
```

Insert rundate as a column in that dataframe

```
data["rundate"] = inpdate
```

By default this column rundate gets added as the last column, I want to reindex it and place it as the first column.

Currently when I do a `print(data.columns)` I get the following output

```
Index([        0,         1,         2,         3,         4,         5,
               6,        'rundate'],
      dtype='object')
```

What I want is

```
Index([        'rundate',    0,         1,         2,         3,         
                  4,         5,         6,],
      dtype='object')
```

All examples I see online have fixed set of columns like the one below:

```
columnsTitles = ['year', 'reports', 'county']
df.reindex(columns=columnsTitles)
```

The columns I generate are coming from reading the csv files dynamically. Any other way I can get the rundate to appear as the first column?

Comment: You don't want to reindex... just select your data frame with all columns in the order you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try with `insert` then, it inserts the new column to first:

```
data.insert(0, 'rundate', inpdate)
```

Or you can reorder column order by passing list of column names such that last column is at first and remaining appended after it:

```
data = data[data.columns[-1:].tolist()+data.columns[:-1].tolist()]
```

Comment: Yes this worked fine - I had a related queston `data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\x01", header=None)`; file is a textfile in a directory, sometimes the textfile is blank, and the code throws an exception, how do I output a blank csv when the textfile is blank?